# Dataflow job is not picking up on new Spanner change stream tables for replication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I have a change stream that's watching all my Spanner tables.
A dataflow job is listening to the change stream, and writes my data into BigQuery.

However, when adding new tables to Spanner, the Dataflow pipeline seems to not pick up on the new watched table.

I am using the default (off the shelf) Spanner to BigQuery - Dataflow job [`--template-file-gcs-location=gs://dataflow-templates-us-central1/2023-08-01-00_RC00/flex/Spanner_Change_Streams_to_BigQuery`]

##### What I've tried

- I made sure the Change stream is capturing all, by re-running `ALTER CHANGE STREAM AllStream SET FOR ALL;` successfully.
- I've restarted my dataflow job (canceled old one, and started a fresh one)

However, my new table is not being replicated (not showing up in my BigQuery dataset). Any suggestion on what else I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an excellent point you are making and your observations are corerct. The `Spanner change streams to BigQuery` Dataflow template does not apply schema changes. Instead, the recommended workflow is to:

1. Cancel the Dataflow pipeline and note the low watermark
2. Apply the changes in BigQuery
3. Apply the changes in Spanner
4. Create a new pipeline with the same configuration as the original one and the previous low watermark as start timestamp

Let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. What do you mean by "applying" changes in BigQuery and Spanner? There are no "changes per se". The spanner schema can be updated at any time, and equally, what am I supposed to change in BigQuery? All that is specified is a source data set (in the dataflow job). How do I specify the watermark as the starting point? I couldn't find a way to inspect the current watermark, nor pass it into a dataflow job (when restarting the default template via CLI)

Comment: Hi @MichaelBrenndoerfer, let me clarify - the recommend workflow is to 1) stop the Dataflow pipeline before making schema changes, note the low watermark 2) Make the schema changes in Spanner 3) Create the newly added tables in BigQuery and 4) Rerun the pipeline with the watermark noted in 1 as start timestamp.

Comment: Thanks Manit, yes that's what I meant: as of now you have to manually keep the tables in sync.